# How to call another navgraph fragment from another nav graph without lossing current destination in andorid

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, navgraph

I have Two navgraph inside my project

- **graphA** {
  I have some fragments inside my ( Graph A )
  **login fragment**  ( this fragment set as home ) and
  **signup fragment**
  }
- **graphB** {
  I have some fragments inside my ( Graph B )
- home ( this fragment set as home )
- profile
  }

---

**Scenario** {
once user get logged In successfully **I want to navigate user to -> graphB(Profile Page)**
but once user press back button he go back to **Graph B (Home Fragment)**
}

Answer (score 0):

In logged successfully response you redirect your fragment to profile page

```
            findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.navigation_profile_page)
```

and on back button redirect the home fragment

```
            findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.navigation_home)
```